# Trying to convert a .txt file into .npy file to split and use for train/validation/test

Tags: python, deep-learning, dataset, numpy

I have a large data set in `.txt` form, and was trying to split it into three for testing, validation, and training by transforming the data into a `.npy` form then load it and use it on my model.

Is such a thing even possible? And if so, what should I do to make it happen?

Please excuse if my question is not logical or unreasonable, I am just trying to learn stuff.

the data should look something like this, keep in mind it is a huge amount of data
[image]

the first 2 lines as requested:

0.60927    -0.35816    -0.10597    0.095495           0    0.063161   -0.064612           0           0   -0.053995  -0.0051178           0           0           0           0           0     0.96824     0.32552     0.44348    0.011149           0     0.13371   0.0014431           0           0    0.074547  -0.0050623           0           0           0           0           0
0.65083    0.090205     0.05407    0.046624           0     0.14346   -0.086913           0           0    -0.01106   0.0072273           0           0           0           0           0    0.057936      0.5131     0.18093   -0.089536           0    0.023838   0.0032454           0           0     0.10316 -0.00034063           0           0           0           0           0

Comment: Is that tabulated data? If so can you show 2-3 lines of it for the discussion?

Comment: No it is not tabulated, I attached a photo of how it looks like you may want to take a look.

Comment: I am wondering whether the space between two numbers is by `' '` or by `\t`. For me to verify, can you just copy the complete first and second lines of the file and paste it here? It's okay even if it is too long. I expect the first line would be the header and the second would be data.

Comment: I copied them is that how you want to see them? or did I done it wrong?

Comment: Thank you. Your text data helped because now I know that there is only one space character between two numbers, unlike what I see in the photo. Text data is generally needed in this place :)

Answer (score 1):

You can read the txt like this. Note that I added `header=None` because I assume your file does NOT contain a header line, but please remove it if it does have it.

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('file_path.txt', sep=' ', header=None)
```

Then convert it to the numpy array format

```
data_npy = data.values
```

(Optional) Shuffle it.

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(1)
np.random.shuffle(data_npy)
```

Split it into three sets, in a ratio of 6:2:2

```
num_rows = data_npy.shape[0]
data_npy1 = data_npy[:int(num_rows*.6)]
data_npy2 = data_npy[int(num_rows*.6): int(num_rows*.8)]
data_npy3 = data_npy[int(num_rows*.8):]
```

And lastly save them.

```
np.save('file_path1.npy', data_npy1)
np.save('file_path2.npy', data_npy2)
np.save('file_path3.npy', data_npy3)
```

**UPDATE**

Check number of entities per line

```
num_lines = 10

with open('file_path.txt', 'r') as f:
    for i in range(num_lines):
        num_entities = f.readline().split(' ')
        print(f'Line {i} has {num_entities} entities')
```

Comment: when I try to read the data it gives `ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 235 fields in line 2, saw 237`

Comment: Seems that the program saw only `235` fields in line 1 so it expects the same number in all subsequent lines. Now I think the most important thing is to **find out what the correct number of field is**, before deciding what to do next. If only line 1 or line 2 has the wrong number of field, the quickest way is to make manual adjustment. if not, then we may need more dedicated code for that.

Comment: I've been trying to solve this but it feels like nothing works, how am I supposed to know what is the correct number of fields?

Comment: Is the first line of your data file a header line, or not a header line?

Comment: No it's not a header line.

Comment: I have added code to print the # fields for the first 10 lines, you can change to look at more lines. If just one has a different number of fields, you may consider to just remove that line. HOWEVER, the correct way should be to ask your data provider for how to use the data.

Comment: Also I was wondering, does this method assigns any specific type for the data like string, float, etc?

Comment: Thank you so so much for your help, I'll try this.

Comment: when you use `pd.read_csv`, the default behavior is that pandas will interpret the datatype itself, so yes, it assigns datatype. You can go to this doc https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html and read about the input argument `dtype` for more.

Comment: That is such a great help. Again, thank you so much!